# How to replace findViewById in kotlin? (Exoplayer and RTMP)

Tags: kotlin, rtmp, exoplayer, findviewbyid

I'm working with Exoplayer RTMP player but I'm facing this problem.

This is the screenshot and I don't know how to replace findViewById.
[image: This is the screenshot and I don't know how to replace findViewById]

I am new to kotlin and really don't know how to replace this. How do I do this?

Comment: Please share your code and dont use picture!

Comment: Okay I will, thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

**In Activity :**

```
 mEditText = findViewById(R.id.edittext_id)
```

**In fragment :**

```
mButtonContinue = requireView().findViewById(R.id.button_id)
```

Comment: Thank you!! this is helpful. But when I am using requireView, it turns out unresolved reference. any idea?

Comment: What did u mean about unresolved reference? i think we dont have other way

Answer (score 0):

With Kotlin you can directly call the ID of your XML and be done with it, without using `findViewById`
In your case you can juste use `simple_player.player = player`

[Kotlin doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html)